# How to make an API call to another one of my views?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a simple investment-tracker app, which should get stock prices from an api and display them nicely for the user. I am having trouble, however to pass the necessary data through to the API call.

views.py

```
class PortfolioData(APIView):
   authentication_classes = []
   permission_classes = []

   def get(self, request, tickers ,format=None):
       # how do I pass the tickers?
       stock_data = get_multiple_stock_details(tickers) # returns JSON response

       return Response(stock_data)

@login_required
   def portfolio(request):
     user = request.user
     user_portfolio = Portfolio.objects.filter(user=user).first()

     return render(request, 'app/portfolio.html', {'portfolio':user_portfolio})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="homepage"),
    path('api/portfolio/data/', views.PortfolioData.as_view(), 
    name="portfolio-data"),
    path('portfolio/', views.portfolio, name='portfolio'), 
]
```

On the frontend I would make an ajax call to my PortfolioData view, in order to be able to process the data on the frontend. My biggest issue is how to pass the needed parameters.
I tried to get the ticker  symbols from the frontend using jQuery and then pass that to the endpoint url but I am not sure if this is the best way to go about this.

Comment: not sure what you mean, exactly... But, make ```api/portfolio/data/``` data dynamic variable here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,,,

## urls.py

```
'''
You should bind two different url with same view. One with dynamic variable and another without it.
'''

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="homepage"),
    path('api/portfolio/', views.PortfolioData.as_view(), name='api_portfolio'), # use unique name for each URL
    path('api/portfolio/<tickers>/', views.PortfolioData.as_view(), name='api_portfolio_data'), # use unique name for each URL
    path('portfolio/', views.portfolio, name='portfolio'), 
]
```

## views.py

```
class PortfolioData(APIView):
   authentication_classes = []
   permission_classes = []

   def get(self, request, tickers=None ,format=None):
        if tickers is None:
            # GET /api/portfolio/ 
            print('No tickers parameter in URL')
            # implement your logic when tickers is not passed.
            return Response(JSON_DATA)
        # GET /api/portfolio/tickers1/
        # implement your logic when tickers is passed.
        stock_data = get_multiple_stock_details(tickers) # returns JSON response
        return Response(stock_data)
```

Now, when make `HTTP GET` request (Does not matter, it's `AJAX` call or not).

> http://localhost:8000/api/portfolio/

`tickers` variable will be `None` this case.

> http://localhost:8000/api/portfolio/ticker1/

`tickers` variable will be `ticker1` `str` this case.

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, that does help! Follow up question: If I don't know the exact numbers of tickers being passed, could I use *args to pass them through also?

Comment: You want to say that, sometimes ```tickers``` are passed as a parameter and sometimes not ? how to implement this logic ?

Comment: I updated ```urls.py``` and  ```views.py```, check both.